# Display posts from followers and logged-in user

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display posts from the users being followed and the logged in user using a single PHP mysql query.

I have three tables:
 - Users (id, name, password)
 - Posts (id, body, date, user_id)
 - Followers (id, user_id, follower_id)

followers.follower_id = person who does the following
followers.user_id = person who is being followed
$_SESSION['id'] = id of the logged in user

```
DB::query('
SELECT users.name, posts.body 
FROM users, posts, followers 
WHERE posts.user_id = followers.user_id 
AND users.id = posts.user_id 
AND followers.follower_id = :userid', 
array(':userid'=>$_SESSION['id'])
);
```

But the query only shows posts from the users being followed, not from the logged in user. How do I fix this?

I have already created a relation between the posts table and the users table.

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `body` varchar(160) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Which table tracks the logged in status?

Comment: If you want the best possible solution in the shortest possible time, provide a complete, verifiable question by posting an sqlfiddle demo with the relevant tables and a sufficient amount of sample data.  This way volunteers don't have to waste any time trying to mock up your table to test their suggested queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include 2 criteria in your `WHERE` clause: Either the creator of the post matches your `:userid` variable, or the follower matches your `:userid`.

Please use current join syntax: This makes your query a lot easier to read.

Your final query should be something like this (I'm excluding the PHP part):

```
SELECT users.name, posts.body
FROM posts
    INNER JOIN users ON
        users.id = Posts.user_id
    -- use left join to handle when a 
    -- user has no followers
    LEFT JOIN Followers ON
        Followers.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE
    users.id = :userid
    OR followers.follower_id = :userid
```